# Vim: open file in right split

Tags: vim

If I'm editing a file in vim, and I want to create a vertical split and open a new file in the right-hand side of the split, is there a way to do that with a single command? If I do:

```
:vsp filename.txt
```

Then it opens the file in the left-hand side of the split.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You can set the following to open new split panes to right

`:set splitright`

Comment: Just to add to that, `:set splitbelow` will be the vertical version of splitright

Comment: Sadly it only work if I restart the vim, not directly work on netrw. ah. (using gvim 8.2 windows 64)

Comment: @BenyaminLimanto I have `set splitright` as well as `let g:netrw_altv=1` in my `vimrc` and it'll open on the left if I hit enter over a file while using netrw, but if I use the 'v' shortcut (open in split view) -- it works as I expect.

Comment: With ':bo term' open my split always goes below the current window. What to do? I want both my bottom term and right split together

Answer (score 43):

```
:bo[tright] vs filename
```

does what you want.

You can add the two lines below to your `~/.vimrc` to make that the default behavior:

```
set splitbelow
set splitright
```

Comment: Could you please explain how is this command ```:bo[tright] vs filename``` different to ```:set splitright``` ?

Comment: @anishjp The former is **explicit**: it opens the new window to the right of the current one. The latter is **implicit**: it tells Vim to always do new windows to the right of the current one.

Answer (score 23):

Well, we used to

```
:vsp filename.txt
```

to open another window in vim. Then you can use

```
ctrl+w r
```

to swap the two window

Answer (score 11):

Use

```
:botright vnew filename.txt
```

As seen in http://technotales.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/vim-splits-a-guide-to-doing-exactly-what-you-want/

Comment: If you want to specify a width for the split, it could be something like `:botright 70vnew filename.txt`. It will set the new split width to 70